# curl server certificate verification failed

Tags: php, linux, ssl, curl

I have a bunch of PHP scripts that use curl to communicate with various services. Currently, one of those services' SSL certificate got updated and my curl started crying about it when I try to get it from my server's CLI:

```
~$ curl https://example.com

curl: (60) server certificate verification failed. CAfile: /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt CRLfile: none
More details here: http://curl.haxx.se/docs/sslcerts.html

curl performs SSL certificate verification by default, using a "bundle" of Certificate Authority (CA) public keys (CA certs). If the default bundle file isn't adequate, you can specify an alternate file using the --cacert option.
If this HTTPS server uses a certificate signed by a CA represented in the bundle, the certificate verification probably failed due to a problem with the certificate (it might be expired, or the name might not match the domain name in the URL).

If you'd like to turn off curl's verification of the certificate, use the -k (or --insecure) option.
```

Currently, I hardcoded `verify => false` to all of my requests in order to keep my scripts operating but that's not something I would like to have laying around.

I got the latest [cacert file from mozilla](https://curl.haxx.se/ca/cacert.pem), put it in `/etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt` and then ran `sudo update-ca-certificates` which ran successfully (I suppose..)

```
~$ sudo update-ca-certificates
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...
done.
```

But then again curl is not too happy about it, still can't get my resource without passing the `-k` flag.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `openssl s_client` command to further debug the issue, in order to find out what exactly seems to be the problem with the certificate.

```
openssl s_client -showcerts -servername myservice.com -connect myservice.com:443
```

Comment: That's some useful information, thank you. It says `verify error:num=18:self signed certificate` but the certificate is clearly not self-signed, it's a COMODO cert. Something is fishy..

Comment: Can you try again with the additional parameter `-servername myservice.com`, it might be related to [this question](https://serverfault.com/questions/726262/ssl-certificate-self-signed-instead-of-valid)?

Comment: Now the error became `verify return code: 21 (unable to verify the first certificate)` so I suppose that's an incorrectly configured server and I must raise an issue with the service maintainers, nothing I could do except skip verification for now.

Comment: yes, supposedly the ca certificate is not correctly bundled with the certificate file. just paste the certificate authority crt into the same file as your certificate and restart the webserver. probably nginx.